# Why is it not possible to iterate?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I wrote a function to view records from a database as the following,

I have tried inserting it into tree and displaying it later but, I am not able to do this, the error below is popping out.

I am not able to understand why this is error is occurring and what it means.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\tp.py", line 532, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\tp.py", line 522, in main
    application = Detail (root)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\tp.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.viewing_record()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\tp.py", line 115, in viewing_record
    for row in db_row:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Function:**

```
  def viewing_record (self):

        record = self.tree.get_children()

        for element in record:

            self.tree.delete(element)

        query = 'SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY Student_Name DESC'

        db_row = self.run_query (query)

        for row in db_row:

            self.tree.insert ('', 0, text = (row[0]), values = (row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9]))
```

I expect it to run and insert values into tree which later would be displayed.

```
def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.1.1.0",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="**",         # your username
                     passwd="***",  
                     db="***")        # name of the data base
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
        db.commit()
        return query_result
```

Comment: Can you print db_row to see what it contains?

Comment: And also paste `run_query` function here.

Comment: The problem lies in `run_query()`: it appears to be returning an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `db_row` is not a an iterable object.

Without a little more to go on in the way of runnable code, I'm afraid the best we can offer is advice.

Try inserting a good old print statement such as:

```
print(db_row)
print(type(db_row))
```

After `db_row = self.run_query (query)` to see what's going on there

Comment: Add the print statements before the `for` loop, as that is where the error seems to be occuring. The error will still occur, but you will also see the printed output.

Comment: I am not able to see it that's I tried adding values to db and also check still its the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Python DB API. Then `run_query` probably is returning the number of rows selected. You need to fetch the results from the cursor used for the query to get the rows fetched. Here's an example from the PyMySQL docs:

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Note the `cursor` object being used to run the query & the `fetchone()` method to get a single row. There's a similar method `fetchall()` to get all the rows in a `list`.  You would be able to traverse that list. 
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that `db_row` is an `int`, and not what you expected.

Try printing `db_row` and see what you got back instead of what your expected...

Comment: It didn't workout still error persists and it is not printing anything

Comment: Then it might be already 'spent' by the time you got to the print. Use `fetchall` as @rdas explained - in your case change `return query_result` to `return query_result.fetchall()`

Comment: but my requirement was to view only that specific record

Comment: It looks like `db_row` is supposed to be more than one row; you iterate `row` on it.